# Has Google Design library a view to make the account switcher like in Gmail?

Tags: android, android-design-library

Has Android Design library a some view to make the account switcher like in Gmail app? I know that there has alternative libraries that has account switcher view. But I use Google Design library and need to make it using only it, so I don't want use another libraries due to one custom view. I only want know whether it has so built-in view or I need to write it manually.